# jQuery add class to children of a tag and children of children of all the tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-tags-input

I need to add a class to all the following tags. The sample JS I have included only adds the class to the direct children tags

before

```
<div name='myDiv'>
    <fieldset>
        <div><input>exmaple</input></input></div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("[name='myDiv']").children().addClass("myClass");
```

after

```
<div name='myDiv'>
    <fieldset class="myClass">
        <div><input>exmaple</input></input></div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

However, the following is the expected result:

```
<div name='myDiv'>
    <fieldset class="myClass">
        <div class="myClass"><inputclass="myClass">exmaple</input></input></div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `*` . see snippet below

P.S. input tags do not need to be closed with `</input>` . you can add a label associated to them if you want

```js
$("[name='myDiv'] *").addClass("myClass");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div name='myDiv'>
    <fieldset>
        <div><input>exmaple</div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, that is it. Thanks.

Comment: glad i could help. do not forget to rank it as accepted . thanks :D